# Getting "Enter the password for your Apple ID to continue using iMessage on this Mac" every time I log in

Tags: macos, messages, ventura

Running a 2020 M1 Macbook Air with Ventura 13.0. Every time I log into the Macbook, I get the prompt "Enter the password for your Apple ID to continue using iMessage on this Mac:". The prompt isn't even for the same iCloud account (although it's for another account in the family group). I have been unsuccessfully finding anything in System Settings or the Message settings.

Comment: In Messages > Settings > iMessage > Settings (subtab), is your preferred Apple ID the one listed?